# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
2.0.0-p247 :006 > load './app/models/user.rb'                                                                                                                                                     
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord                                                                                                                                                    
        from /home/action/iAuth/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                                        
        from (irb):6:in `load'                                                                                                                                                                    
        from (irb):6                                                                                                                                                                              
        from /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'
```

Below is my `User Model`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

When i try to load my `user.rb in my irb`, i get the above error.

Comment: you haven `ActiveRecord::Base` class in irb.

Comment: @Monk_Code: I am not understanding, should i load this class too in IRB

Comment: you cant use your model in `irb console`, use `rails console` instead, look  below answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

start your `irb` session with

`rails console`

and not:

`irb`

`rails console` would load your `rails` environment and your model for you, so you can do things like:

`User.all` or `User.new` without loading the `class` as it has been preloaded by `rails console` already

Comment: Thanks, when i run User i get this info [User(no database connection)] What should i look into

Comment: this normal behavior, use `User.connection`

Comment: @Monk_Code: Thanks, not it says User(Table doesn't exist) . I am sorry pretty new to rails community. I have the migration file, but i did run it before using rake db::migrate

Answer (score 0):

there's another case.

if you are using mongoid ( mongo db adapter) , and you have to make sure in `config/application.rb`, you must require activerecord:

```
require "active_model/railtie"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to run test in a new ruby gem I made.

I added this to the top of spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require "active_record/railtie"
```

and the problem went away.

**But** a better way to solve it (I think) is to require the library in gemspec:

```
  # Uncomment to register a new dependency of your gem
  # spec.add_dependency "example-gem", "~> 1.0"
  spec.add_dependency "rails" # <----- Add this line
```